# Cannot deserialize JSON string to class

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I got error: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'jsonTest.Posts' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.

I must be missing something now... ?

Here is my small console application (I hard coded Json string at this moment):

```html
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
    
    namespace jsonTest
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                
                var responseValue = @"[{""providerName"":""Aktoo"",""providerIcon"":""logo1.png""},{""providerName"":""Aktii"",""providerIcon"":""logo2.png""}]";
                
                Posts posts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Posts>(responseValue);
    
                Console.WriteLine("test" + posts.ProviderName);
                
                
            }
        }
    }
```

and this my Posts class:

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace jsonTest
{
    class Posts
    {
        [JsonProperty("providerName")]
        public string ProviderName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("providerIcon")]
        public string providerIcon { get; set; }
        
    }
}
```

The final version would loop trough all different provieders.

Comment: `List<Posts> posts= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Posts>>(responseValue);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You json is not a single object. its an array of the object so try to deserialize in `List<Post>`

```
List<Posts> posts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Posts>>(responseValue);
```

And then you can iterate over this `posts` by using `foreach`

```
foreach (var item in posts)
{
    Console.WriteLine("providerName: " + item.ProviderName);
    Console.WriteLine("providerIcon: " + item.providerIcon);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

**Output:**

[image]